# Divide $ yy' = (y + 1)^2 $ by $ (y + 1)^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading from [*Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com.gh/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=iU4zDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (Lesson 4C page 36) and came across this question:

**Find a 1-parameter family of solutions of the differential equation**

$$ (a) \quad yy' = (y + 1)^2 $$

**and the particular solution for which $\quad y(2) = 0$**

The first step was to divide $ (a) $ by $ (y + 1)^2 $
and they had 
$$ \int{\frac{y}{(y + 1)^2} dy } = \int dx \quad,\quad y \neq -1$$

but when I was trying to divide $ (a) $ by $ (y + 1)^2 $
I had 
$$ \frac{yy'}{(y+1)^2} = \frac{(y+1)^2}{(y+1)^2} $$
$$ => \quad \frac{yy'}{(y+1)^2} = 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are doing the same thing as you are, but they have just gone a little bit further.

Note that $y'=\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$, so (assuming $y\neq-1$) we may separate

$$\frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\,\mathrm dy=\mathrm dx,$$

then integrate

$$\int\frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\,\mathrm dy=\int\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Starting from @Axion004's answer
$$\frac{1}{y+1}+\ln|y+1|=x+C$$ the condition $y(2)=0$ leads to $C=-1$. Now, let $z=\frac{1}{y+1}$ to get
$$z-\log(|z|)=x-1\implies z=-W\left(-e^{1-x}\right)$$ where appears the  branches of Lambert function (your will learn sooner or later about this beautiful function). Then
$$y=-\frac{1}{W_{0}\left(-e^{1-x}\right)}-1\qquad \text{and} \qquad y=-\frac{1}{W_{-1}\left(-e^{1-x}\right)}-1$$

Answer (score 1):

In differential equations and calculus it is often assumed that

$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

where $y$ is the dependent variable and $x$ is the independent variable. In your case, given $y \neq 1$

$$\frac{yy'}{(y+1)^2} = \frac{(y+1)^2}{(y+1)^2}=1 \implies \frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=1 \implies \frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\,dy=dx$$

by which you can integrate

$$\int \frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\,dy=\int dx$$

by observing that the left-hand side has the following partial fraction decomposition

$$\frac{y}{(y+1)^2}=\frac{1}{y+1}-\frac{1}{(y+1)^2}$$

so that

$$\int \frac{y}{(y+1)^2}\,dy=\int \left(\frac{1}{y+1}-\frac{1}{(y+1)^2}\right)dy=\frac{1}{y+1}+\ln|y+1|+C$$

therefore the implicit solution is

$$\frac{1}{y+1}+\ln|y+1|=x+C$$